# I need to build new recipes for Salesforce APEX code

Tags: format, refactoring, apex, openrewrite

I need to build new recipes for Salesforce APEX code , I started in Java using patterns but I noticed openrewrite have already scanning and need to create recipe. If I pass a class it should give me all blocks like Method, while. for etc, how to achieve this ? Your help is highly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCrgH.png)

Thanks
Dora.

any solution for this need.

Comment: you can improve your question with entering image description

Answer (score 0):

It's not immediately clear to me what you've already read and tried, so I can only give you a rough overview of resources until you have more specific questions.

We have our OpenRewrite docs to take you through [Concepts & explanations](https://docs.openrewrite.org/concepts-explanations); From there you can go through our [Authoring recipes](https://docs.openrewrite.org/authoring-recipes) guides. Be sure to follow the [developing tips](https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/building-openrewrite-from-source#developing-tips) for IntelliJ. If you want to dive deeper into particular topics we [videos on a variety of subjects](https://www.youtube.com/@moderne-auto-remediation/streams). We recommend that you [use our rewrite-recipe-starter project](https://github.com/moderneinc/rewrite-recipe-starter).

Beyond that you're welcome to ask more specific questions. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Tim, I looking for OpenRewrite  API which will take class as input and gives tree structure

Comment: That would be our Visitor class, also explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLCW9Ql7swI&list=PLIasdWXKABOkMjPvKOrYZJLZbpX01mCST&index=4